# Get current nav state in React Native using react-navigation with Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have inherited an existing React Native application, using `react-navigation` for routing and `react-navigation-redux-helpers` to connect it to the Redux store. I'm having some trouble properly implementing the Android back button.

The screen structure looks roughly like this:

```
StackNavigator // Root
- StackNavigator // Authenticated routes
  - StackNavigator // Main screens
    - BottomTabNavigator // Main screens
      - StackNavigator // Profile screen
        - ... // Subscreens
      - StackNavigator // Friends screen
        - ... // Subscreens
      - StackNavigator // Notifications screen
        - ... // Subscreens
    - Component // Overlay screen
    - Component // Overlay screen
    - Component // Overlay screen
  - Component // Overlay screen
  - Component // Overlay screen
  - Component // Overlay screen
- StackNavigator // Login routes
- Component // Loading screen
```

I've modified the example here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-redux-helpers#back-button to also work with the new `createReduxContainer` API:

```
const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator(/* ... */);

class AppNavigator extends createReduxContainer(RootNavigator) {
    componentDidMount() {
        super.componentDidMount && super.componentDidMount();
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid);
        super.componentWillUnmount && super.componentWillUnmount();
    }

    onBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        const { state } = this.getCurrentNavigation();
        // ... do something with state
        dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
        return true;
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    state: state.navigation,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppNavigator);
```

This works for the most part - however, I can't find a way to know if I'm at the "start" of the navigation history so I can let the app exit. I would expect to use the `state` property, but this gives me the navigation state of the root StackNavigator, so the `routes` property always has a length of 1 (containing the "authenticated routes" StackNavigator).

Is there any way to handle this more gracefully with `react-navigation-redux-helpers`, or by changing the router structure somehow? I haven't really been able to find a best practice for this combination (`react-navigation`+`react-navigation-redux-helpers`) and the examples are super simple.

Comment: you want make back button using redux ?

Comment: No, the back button is already there. I want to find the current "global" navigation state regardless of where it is in the hierarchy otherwise.